# How to insert data into particular columns dynamically into a table in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a table with columns : `transaction_name | member1 | member2 | member3 | member4`

In my activity, I will receive a `String` array of column names of this table,
say `columnarray[] = {"member1","member3","member4"}`

and also I will receive a `Integer` array of column values to insert into those particular columns, say `valuearray[] = {value1,value3,value4}`

Now, in my activity, I have to write a query such that i have to insert these values(in integer array) into these columns(in string array) dynamically.

Simply, the following action should be performed :

```
"INSERT into tablename(member1,member3,member4) values(value1,value3,value4)"
```

As I will receive these column names and column values from arrays, how can i perform this insertion operation on my table dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ordinary `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (int i = 0; i < columnarray.length(); i++) {
    values.put(columnarray[i], valuearray[i]);
}
database.insert("tablename", null, values);
```